# When the increasing of sequences $a_n$ leads to increasing of $\frac{1}{a_n}$?

Tags: calculus

I was asked the following question:

> When the increasing of sequences $a_n$ leads to increasing of $\frac{1}{a_n}$?

I could not think of an example. It looks like if $a_n$ is increasing then $\frac{1}{a_n}$ is decreasing. Is it true? If so, how do I prove it formally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\{-1,2,3,...\}$ is increasing and $\{-1,\frac 1  2,  \frac  1 3,...\}$ is neither increasing nor decreasinig.

If $a_n$'s are all positive or all negative then $(\frac  1 {a_n})$ is necessarily decreasing because the function $f(x)=\frac  1 x$ is decreasing on both  $(0,\infty)$ and $(-\infty,0)$.

Comment: So the answer to the question is never?

Comment: @vesii That is correct.

Answer (score 1):

If the sequence $a_n$ is increasing and has constant sign for all $n$, then it is true that $1/a_n$ decreases.

To prove this, assume $a_n < a_{n+1}$. Divide both sides of the inequality by $a_n a_{n+1}$ (which is positive since $a_n$ and $a_{n+1}$ have same sign) to obtain $1/a_{n+1} < 1/a_n$.

If the sequence $a_n$ has both negative and positive terms, this is not true. For example, if $a_1 = -2$ and $a_2 = 2$, then $1/a_1 = -1/2$ and $1/a_2 = 1/2$.